# CSS for Stack Overflow site not showing up correctly

Tags: support, cdn

I can post on meta with no issue. But for some odd reason I am not seeing the full-blown Stack Overflow site. It appears the CSS is missing from most of it.

[image]

When I try to hit the [CDN at this link](https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=8a7874f4f2dd), this is what I get:

> The webpage at cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=8a7874f4f2dd might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address

Comment: it's probably an issue with out CDN. please refresh.

Comment: been refreshing all day and rebooted and cleared cookies.

Comment: Just got the problem 3 times in 1 hour. Refreshing doesn't solve the problem. You just have to wait.

Comment: @JonH Great! A friend of mine had the same problem like an hour ago on all of his browsers and asked if I had the same problem but I didn't. It went away after a while but this certainly is some kind of bug.

Comment: Been trying since 7am with the same issue.

Comment: @Jon browse to [this link](https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=8a7874f4f2dd) directly... what you get?

Comment: The webpage at https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=8a7874f4f2dd might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Comment: Maybe ipv6 problem then, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185136/152859)

Comment: Working okay for me...

Comment: @Jon another one... go to [this test page](http://test-ipv6.com/) if you have ipv6 address detected you might need to disable it as described in the other post.

Comment: I see this occasionally and it seems to just be connection blip related - the CSS couldn't load for whatever reason (usually when I'm connected to a slow VPN). In this case it sounds like you have a more serious issue - from your end the CDN is down.

Comment: Jin has been hard at work on the new "craigslist style" redesign.

Comment: @anyone - has any of the developers @ stackoverflow or mods had a chance to look at this?

Comment: @JonH can you send me a traceroute please? craver@stackoverflow.com

Comment: @NickCraver - Thanks I just sent you a trace route.

Comment: @NickCraver - Did you get my email?  Have you guys had a chance to look at this?

Comment: @JonH only a handful of users are seeing this...every single case so far is a bad proxy at their place of work.  I'm going through the responses to our additional info requests now.  Your issue is definitely local to the workplace, what type of proxy are you behind?

Comment: @JonH also, we are looking at the raw logs on the CloudFlare side, we're just simultaneously working with all users who have reported issues (I asked them for the same info I asked of you) to trace them down at once - since that's a *lot* of log data to trace through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up resolving this although it was not an easy solution.  We were using EdgeWave's iPrism to authenticate users out to the web.  It's not a proxy and it definitely wasn't blocking Stack Overflow or even the CDNs. The issue was the CDN IP address seemed to be changing and we think the iPrism thought this was some sort of spoofing.  In any event we managed to add the IP addresses given to us by CloudFlare as exceptions within the iPrism interface.  Once we did that Stack Overflow was working.