# Unable to post question on stackoverflow.com for user 'user2671890'

Tags: support

When I try lo ask a question on the stackoverflow.com, I don't see a toolbar on the edit area nor do I get to post my question. It doesn't give me an error, but it simply cycles back to the same page.

Also, when I try to edit the user profile, I get the following error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!

What else do I need to do to be able to post question on this site?

Comment: Do you happen to have javascript disabled? Are you getting any javascript/network errors? What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Can you access http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?

Comment: Arjan: no I can't browse i get an error like "Oops! Google Chrome could not find cdn.sstatic.net
Did you mean: sstatic.­net"

Comment: Oded: not really, I am able to post on the meta.stackoverflow.com so I think the brower should not be an issue here. BTW I just registered today, is there a limit on how long I have to wait before I can post?

Comment: @Kiran - No time limits, but if you can't find `cdn.sstatic.net` there may very well be a network problem on your end (possibly a proxy that is filtering out https).

Comment: @Oded, HTTPS is (temporarily) not used anymore, [unless one explicitly wants to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191338/https-problem-when-accessing-stack-overflow-in-china/191589#191589), right?

Comment: Meta does not use the CDN for JavaScript, which is apparently why you don't have problems here. And yes, the browser might matter: [Can't ask a question when IE Tracking Protection is enabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80044/cant-ask-a-question-when-ie-tracking-protection-is-enabled). (See also [Replying in comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply) to ensure people get notified.)

Comment: @Arjan - Wasn't sure about that. But regardless if the browser can't access the CDN, the OP will have problems

Comment: True, @Oded. Do you know if the [list of things that can help the support people at the CDN to debug issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97663/intermittent-responses-from-cdn/100102#100102) is still up-to-date?

Comment: @Arjan - step 5 is most certainly out of date, we are no longer using netdna, AFAIK we are now using CloudFlare. Most other steps are pretty correct (except for the actual hosts).

Comment: @Arjan: I can reach http://sstatic.net/js/stub.js but not http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js BTW step 5 says "You are hitting the NetDNA London Datacenter" not sure if its still relevant.

Comment: Without the "cdn" part, you're going to the Stack Exchange servers directly (198.252.206.16), not to the CloudFare CDN. That's all I know; maybe @Oded (being a SE employee) knows more. Still, he'll want to know: what OS? Which browser? Which provider? Did you try another browser and maybe another device in the same network? Are you on mobile? Anything else that might be special? Does London make sense?

Comment: And @Oded, do you feel it makes sense that http://sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net/js/stub.js gives me "Error 1001
DNS resolution error"? (Might very well be normal, but given the output of `dig cdn.sstatic.net` that includes `cdn.sstatic.net. 2 IN CNAME sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net.`, I figured that name might work too.)

Comment: Are you using IPv6? (The error in my last comment shows I'm using IPv6 to access that error page; and so does `curl -vi "http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js"` However, forcing IPv4 for the long domain gets me the same error page; `curl --ipv4 -v "http://sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net/js/stub.js"`)

Comment: @Arjan - I don't really know... Something for someone else in the team

Comment: On a working day, @Oded ;-) In case Kiran is on IPv6: I found [a nice debugging link](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/90336bfcff65c12ee97d57f05e0ce2df/detail) showing "lame referrals" in [Problems with CDN DNS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182594/problems-with-cdn-dns). Clicking the yellow alert icon explains, but I've no clue if that means trouble or not. It seems it might match the error *"Oops! Google Chrome could not find cdn.sstatic.net"* though...

Comment: @Arjan - nice resource there. Lame referrer does seem to point to a problem (a DNS server that points you to _less_ authoritative servers probably does mean a misconfig _somewhere_).

Comment: Kiran, if you don't know if you're on IPv6, or if it's preferred when available, then see *"When both protocols are available, your browser uses ..."* on http://ipv6-test.com

Comment: Ah, @Oded, I was wrong: [that](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/90336bfcff65c12ee97d57f05e0ce2df/detail) debugging link was actually timestamped (even though the progress seemed to indicate things were live; when running a new test you'll also see *"fingerprinting servers"* when all is done, which I guess saves a lot of information to rebuild the result later). Anyway, [all seems fine today](http://dns.squish.net/traverses/16b85c8d9e5ed855572a0b0138c7f0da/detail).

Comment: Sorry, @Oded, me again. Maybe it is live after all; somehow both results have different root servers. Well, I don't know, someone who actually understands these things might want to peek at both links and maybe create yet another test run ;-)

Comment: @Arjan - That rules me out ;)

Comment: I just came in to office and tried to connect and today everything is working just fine !! so looks like my internet provider at home had something to do with it.  I had tried using IE, Chrome, Firefox on on my Win7 and also on my Android 4.1 but nothing worked. I'll try to give it a try again this evening and see if its resolved automagically today even there. Thanks for your help so far. Regards Kiran

Comment: At work and at home, does http://ipv6-test.com indicate you're on IPv6? If yes, in a command prompt, does `nslookup -type=AAAA cdn.sstatic.net` (alternatively: `host -t AAAA cdn.sstatic.net` for Mac, Linux and all) include IPv6 addresses, such as `2400:cb00:2048:1::be5d:f43a`. If not, does using Google's DNS help, by using `nslookup -type=AAAA cdn.sstatic.net 8.8.8.8` instead? And if Google's DNS helps, which internet provider are you with?

Comment: (See also a Firefox-only workaround for IPv6 issues, in [Stack Overflow static assets not loading](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185136/stackoverflow-static-assets-not-loading).)

Comment: (Any luck with the debugging, Kiran?)

Comment: @Arjan: not really as everything is just working fine for me. may be it was some intermittent connection issue. BTW I am not on ipv6 to my knowledge and is what suggested by ipv6-test.com also nsloopup gives me the following: 

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    sstatic.net.cdn.cloudflare.net
Addresses:  2400:cb00:2048:1::be5d:f53a
          2400:cb00:2048:1::be5d:f63a
          2400:cb00:2048:1::be5d:f43a
Aliases:  cdn.sstatic.net   ..... any ways the site is working now, so nothing much to complain at the moment. I'll try this again when i face a similar issue. Thanks, Kiran